# Blazor breaking div

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I am using .NET 5 and blazor.

I am getting very confused why this code works fine:

```
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <DonutChart GadgetData="@DashboardData.GadgetData.ToList()[0]" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <DonutChart GadgetData="@DashboardData.GadgetData.ToList()[1]" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <DonutChart GadgetData="@DashboardData.GadgetData.ToList()[2]" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

But when I try to put some logic and try to construct a similar structure it breaks my div's:

```
    @foreach (GadgetData gadgetData in DashboardData.GadgetData)
    {
        switch (GadgetCounter) 
        {
            case 1:
                @:<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <DonutChart GadgetData="@gadgetData" />
                        <br />
                        <p>@GadgetCounter</p>
                    </div>
                break;
            case 2:
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <DonutChart GadgetData="@gadgetData" />
                    <br />
                    <p>@GadgetCounter</p>
                </div>
                break;
            case 3:
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                      <DonutChart GadgetData="@gadgetData" />
                      <br />
                      <p>@GadgetCounter</p>
                  </div>
                @:</div>
                GadgetCounter = 0;
                break;
        }

        GadgetCounter += 1;
    }
```

I was also displaying the counter to be sure that is correct:

```
<p>@GadgetCounter</p>
```

and yes it shows properly 1,2 and 3.

The HTML it creates is this:

```
<div class="row"></div>

<div class="col-md-4">
   ......
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  ......
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
 ......
</div>
```

As you can see the row div does not contain the column divs.
Any suggestion, please?

Comment: Move `@:<div class="row">` and `@:</div>` outside  of `foreach` loop?

Comment: Also, consider doing the opening and closing div _outside_ of the loop, then you may not need a switch at all.

Comment: I can't move outside of the foreach because I am injecting components. And I can have 3 components or maybe 9, or any random number of components to inject. If I have 9, I want to create 3 rows and each row should have 3 columns

Comment: outside of the loop is not possible as I explained before

Comment: @mjwills case 1: inject the first component so it has the row div and the first column div (col-md-4), case 2 inject the second component that will be placed in the second column of the row, so I don't put the row div, and the case 3 it closes to row div and the counter starts again in case there are more component to inject, so will start a new row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the following code.If `i+3>=DashboardData.GadgetData.Count()`,only iterator from `i` to `DashboardData.GadgetData.Count()-1`.If `i+3<DashboardData.GadgetData.Count()`,only iterator from `i` to `i+3`:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < DashboardData.GadgetData.Count(); i = i + 3)
{
    var j = (i + 3 < DashboardData.GadgetData.Count()) ? i + 3:DashboardData.GadgetData.Count();
    <div class="row">
        @for (int k = i; k < j; k++)
        {
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <DonutChart GadgetData="@DashboardData.GadgetData[k]" />   
            </div>
        }

    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working better, but I still need to consider the cases when the Take() will have 1 or 2 elements.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < DashboardData.GadgetData.Count(); i=i+3)
    {
        var items = DashboardData.GadgetData.Skip(i).Take(3);

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <DonutChart GadgetData="@items.ToList()[0]" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <DonutChart GadgetData="@items.ToList()[1]" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <DonutChart GadgetData="@items.ToList()[2]" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: Use `ToList` before assigning to `items` rather than three times.

Comment: Why don't you just index GadgetData directly with a variable that is a i+0, i+1 and i+2? All the skip/take/tolist seems unnecessary